# Plotting Histogram: How can I do it from scratch using data stored in a database?

Tags: python, mysql, graph, gnuplot, histogram

I have some data stored in a database like this:

TableName: faults
Table:

```
+------------+--------------+
| fault_type | total        |
+------------+--------------+
|    1       |            1 | 
|    2       |            3 | 
|    3       |            8 | 
|    4       |            2 | 
.............................
```

How am I supposed to get a histogram plot starting from this table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution below assumes that you have MySQL, Python and GNUPlot. The specific details can be fine tuned if necessary. Posting it so that it could be a baseline for other peers.

**Step #1: Decide the type of graph.**

If it is a frequency plot of some kind, then a simple SQL query should do the trick:

```
select total, count(total) from faults GROUP BY total;
```

If you need to specify bin sizes, then proceed to the next step.

**Step #2: Make sure you are able to connect to MySQL using Python. You can use the MySQLdb import to do this.**

After that, the python code to generate data for a histogram plot is the following (this was written precisely in 5 minutes so it is very crude):

```
import MySQLdb

def DumpHistogramData(databaseHost, databaseName, databaseUsername, databasePassword, dataTableName, binsTableName, binSize, histogramDataFilename):
    #Open a file for writing into
    output = open("./" + histogramDataFilename, "w")

    #Connect to the database
    db = MySQLdb.connect(databaseHost, databaseUsername, databasePassword, databaseName)
    cursor = db.cursor()

    #Form the query
    sql = """select b.*, count(*) as total 
            FROM """ + binsTableName + """ b 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN """ + dataTableName + """ a 
            ON a.total between b.min AND b.max 
            group by b.min;"""
    cursor.execute(sql)

    #Get the result and print it into a file for further processing
    count = 0;
    while True:
        results = cursor.fetchmany(10000)
        if not results:
            break
        for result in results:
            #print >> output, str(result[0]) + "-" + str(result[1]) + "\t" + str(result[2])
    db.close()

def PrepareHistogramBins(databaseHost, databaseName, databaseUsername, databasePassword, binsTableName, maxValue, totalBins):

    #Connect to the database    
    db = MySQLdb.connect(databaseHost, databaseUsername, databasePassword, databaseName)
    cursor = db.cursor()

    #Check if the table was already created
    sql = """DROP TABLE IF EXISTS """ + binsTableName
    cursor.execute(sql)

    #Create the table
    sql = """CREATE TABLE """ + binsTableName + """(min int(11), max int(11));"""
    cursor.execute(sql)

    #Calculate the bin size
    binSize = maxValue/totalBins

    #Generate the bin sizes
    for i in range(0, maxValue, binSize):
        if i is 0:
            min = i
            max = i+binSize
        else:
            min = i+1
            max = i+binSize
        sql = """INSERT INTO """ + binsTableName + """(min, max) VALUES(""" + str(min) + """, """ + str(max) + """);"""
        cursor.execute(sql)
    db.close()
    return binSize

binSize = PrepareHistogramBins("localhost", "testing", "root", "", "bins", 5000, 100)
DumpHistogramData("localhost", "testing", "root", "", "faults", "bins", binSize, "histogram")
```

**Step #3: Use GNUPlot to generate the histogram. You can use the following script as a starting point (generates an eps image file):**

```
set terminal postscript eps color lw 2 "Helvetica" 20
set output "output.eps"
set xlabel "XLABEL"
set ylabel "YLABEL"
set title "TITLE"
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster gap 1
set style fill solid border -1
set boxwidth 0.9
set key autotitle columnheader
set xtics rotate by -45
plot "input" using 1:2 with linespoints ls 1
```

Save the above script into some arbitrary file say, sample.script. Proceed to the next step.

**Step #4: Use gnuplot with the above input script to generate an eps file**

```
gnuplot sample.script
```

Nothing complicated but I figured a couple of bits from this code can be reused. Again, like I said, it is not perfect but you can get the job done :)

Credits:

- Ofri Raviv (for helping me out with
  the MySQL query in this post:
  [Getting data for histogram plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764881/mysql-getting-data-for-histogram-plot))
- Myself (for writing the python and
  gnuplot script :D)

Answer (score 0):

[This blog article](http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.com/2011/09/statistic-analysis-and-histogram.html) may help you! It talks about statistic using gnuplot and plot the result into histogram.