# sql : calculate the total birthday moth based on month

Tags: sql

I want to code a query to calculate the total birthday moth based on month . Here is the sample data . Two person's bithday are April, 1980 .

How to write this query ?

```
John    02/21/1980
Peter   02/22/1980
Lucy    04/21/1980

------ result -----
01/1980     0
02/1980     2
03/1980     0
04/1980     1
05/1980     0
.....
```

Comment: MySQL/SqlServer/Oracle? Based on month and year or only month?

Comment: Have you tried anything besides asking here?

Comment: And using standard sql, how would YOUR approach be at generating date ranges/missing dates/date gaps??? **I think that this question is over generalized, and if you wish to keep it open, you need to specify a little more detail.**

Answer (score 3):

You can loop for every months like this:

```
DECLARE @month INT 
DECLARE @year INT
DECLARE @result TABLE (MonthYear varchar(7),BirthdaysCount INT)
SET @month = 1
SET @year = 1980

WHILE(@month < 13)
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @result
    SELECT (CAST(@month as VARCHAR) + '/' + CAST(@year as VARCHAR)),
            COUNT(*)
    FROM test
    WHERE MONTH(birth) = @month AND YEAR(birth) = @year
    SET @month = @month + 1
  END

select * from @result
```

See the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/20692/2

Comment: This is getting each time less "standard sql" :)

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you would do this:

```
select concat(month(dob), '/', year(dob)) monthYear, count(*) cnt from t
group by monthYear
order by year(dob), month(dob)
```

However, in order to get the "missing dates" you'll have to generate data, because `01/1980` is not in any table, as far as I can see. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034668/missing-days-from-sql-call-where-there-is-no-data/10081549#10081549) to see how.

Answer (score 0):

how about this for sql-server

```
create table #temp
(
    name varchar(50),
    DOB datetime
)

insert into #temp values ('john', '2/21/1980')
insert into #temp values ('peter', '2/22/1980')
insert into #temp values ('lucy', '4/21/1980')

select convert(varchar(2), MONTH(DOB)) + '/' + Convert(varchar(4), YEAR(DOB)) as [MM/YYYY]
    , count(*) as TotalCount
from #temp
group by convert(varchar(2), MONTH(DOB)) + '/' + Convert(varchar(4), YEAR(DOB))

drop table #temp
```

EDIT - This will get you all records for the dates included in the dates in the table. It will use the Min/Max Date in the table to get the date range, you then use this range to get the count of the birthdays in each month:

```
create table #temp
(
    name varchar(50),
    DOB datetime
)

insert into #temp values ('john', '2/21/1980')
insert into #temp values ('peter', '2/22/1980')
insert into #temp values ('lucy', '4/21/1980')

;with cte as
(
    select min(DOB) as MinDate, max(DOB) as MaxDate
    from #temp
    union all
    SELECT dateadd(mm, 1, t.MinDate), t.MaxDate
    from cte t
    where dateadd(mm, 1, t.MinDate) <= t.MaxDate
)
select convert(varchar(2), MONTH(c.MinDate)) + '/' + Convert(varchar(4), YEAR(c.MinDate))
    , IsNull(t.TotalCount, 0) as TotalCount
from cte c
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT convert(varchar(2), MONTH(DOB)) + '/' + Convert(varchar(4), YEAR(DOB)) as [MM/YYYY]
        , count(*) as TotalCount
    FROM #temp 
    group by convert(varchar(2), MONTH(DOB)) + '/' + Convert(varchar(4), YEAR(DOB))
) t
    on convert(varchar(2), MONTH(C.MinDate)) + '/' + Convert(varchar(4), YEAR(C.MinDate))
        = t.[MM/YYYY]

drop table #temp
```

Comment: @user595234 fixed answer to provide list of dates between the min/date date in the table and give a count for all records