# How to include dates with zero messages into the resultset anyway?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table with messages:

```
+---------+---------+------------+----------+
| msg_id  | user_id | m_date     |  m_time  |
+-------------------+------------+----------+
|   1     | 1       | 2011-01-22 | 06:23:11 |
|   2     | 1       | 2011-01-23 | 16:17:03 |
|   3     | 1       | 2011-01-23 | 17:05:45 |
|   4     | 2       | 2011-01-22 | 23:58:13 |
|   5     | 2       | 2011-01-23 | 23:59:32 |
|   6     | 2       | 2011-01-24 | 21:02:41 |
|   7     | 3       | 2011-01-22 | 13:45:00 |
|   8     | 3       | 2011-01-23 | 13:22:34 |
|   9     | 3       | 2011-01-23 | 18:22:34 |
|  10     | 3       | 2011-01-24 | 02:22:22 |
|  11     | 3       | 2011-01-24 | 13:12:00 |
+---------+---------+------------+----------+
```

What I want is for each day, to see how many messages each user has sent BEFORE and AFTER 16:00:

```
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    m_date, 
    SUM(m_time <= '16:00') AS before16, 
    SUM(m_time > '16:00') AS after16 
FROM messages 
GROUP BY user_id, m_date
ORDER BY user_id, m_date ASC
```

This produces:

```
user_id m_date      before16  after16
-------------------------------------
1       2011-01-22  1         0
1       2011-01-23  0         2
2       2011-01-22  0         1
2       2011-01-23  0         1
2       2011-01-24  0         1
3       2011-01-22  1         0
3       2011-01-23  1         1
3       2011-01-24  2         0
```

Because user 1 has written no messages on 2011-01-24, this date is not in the resultset. However, this is undesirable. I have a second table in my database, called "date_range":

```
+---------+------------+
| date_id | d_date     |
+---------+------------+
| 1       | 2011-01-21 |
| 1       | 2011-01-22 |
| 1       | 2011-01-23 |
| 1       | 2011-01-24 |
+---------+------------+
```

I want to check the "messages" against this table. For each user, all these dates have to be in the resultset. As you can see, none of the users have written messages on 2011-01-21, and as said, user 1 has no messages on 2011-01-24. The desired output of the query would be:

```
user_id d_date      before16  after16
-------------------------------------
1       2011-01-21  0         0
1       2011-01-22  1         0
1       2011-01-23  0         2
1       2011-01-24  0         0
2       2011-01-21  0         0
2       2011-01-22  0         1
2       2011-01-23  0         1
2       2011-01-24  0         1
3       2011-01-21  0         0
3       2011-01-22  1         0
3       2011-01-23  1         1
3       2011-01-24  2         0
```

How can I link the two tables so that the query result also holds rows with zero values for before16 and after16?

**Edit: yes, I have a "users" table:**

```
+---------+------------+
| user_id | user_date  |
+---------+------------+
| 1       | foo        |
| 2       | bar        |
| 3       | foobar     |
+---------+------------+
```

Comment: Instead of a date range (which is FIXED) you should consider what I wrote in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034668/missing-days-from-sql-call-where-there-is-no-data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test bed:

```sql
create table messages (msg_id integer, user_id integer, _date date, _time time);
create table date_range (date_id integer, _date date);
insert into messages values
       (1,1,'2011-01-22','06:23:11'),
       (2,1,'2011-01-23','16:17:03'),
       (3,1,'2011-01-23','17:05:05');
insert into date_range values
       (1, '2011-01-21'),
       (1, '2011-01-22'),
       (1, '2011-01-23'),
       (1, '2011-01-24');
```

Query:

```sql
SELECT p._date, p.user_id,
       coalesce(m.before16, 0) b16, coalesce(m.after16, 0) a16
  FROM
      (SELECT DISTINCT user_id, dr._date FROM messages m, date_range dr) p
  LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT user_id, _date,
              SUM(_time <= '16:00') AS before16,
              SUM(_time > '16:00') AS after16 
         FROM messages 
        GROUP BY user_id, _date
        ORDER BY user_id, _date ASC) m
    ON p.user_id = m.user_id AND p._date = m._date;
```

**EDIT:**

1. Your initial query is left as is, I hope it doesn't requires any explanations;
2. `SELECT DISTINCT user_id, dr._date FROM messages m, date_range dr` will return a cartesian or [`CROSS JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html) of two tables, which will give me all required date range for each user in subject. As I'm interested in each pair only once, I use `DISTINCT` clause. Try this query with and without it;
3. Then I use [`LEFT JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html) on two sub-selects.

   This join means: first, INNER join is performed, i.e. all rows with matching fields in the `ON` condition are returned. Then, for each row in the left-side relation of the join that has no matches on the right side, return `NULL`s (thus the name, `LEFT JOIN`, i.e. left relation is always there and right is expected to have `NULL`s). This join will do what you expect — return `user_id + date` combinations even if there were no messages in the given date for a given user. Note that I use `user_id + date` sub-select first (on the left) and `messages` query second (on the right);
4. [`coalesce()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) is used to replace `NULL` with zero.

I hope this clarifies how this query works.

Comment: I try to understand your query but get confused. I have renamed some of the columns so they are distinct (m_date and d_date, for instance). Could you please update your query so I may follow it better?

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, and thanks for the explaination...but now I get an error: `#1052 - Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous`. This I don't understand. Also: the error doesn't point to WHICH user_id is ambiguous and why...argh!

Comment: That is actually the situation in wich MySQL is. You have 2 (or more) relations that provide `user_id` column in your `FROM` list. In such cases you _must_ prefix column with relation alias(or full table name, if relation is a table). Note, that all columns in `SELECT`, `FROM` AND `ON` clauses have prefixes in my example. This is a good practice to always make aliases for relations and always prefix columns.

Comment: So, the best way would be to write the query like this (including updated column names)? `SELECT p.d_date, p.user_id,
       coalesce(m.before16, 0) b16, coalesce(m.after16, 0) a16
  FROM
      (SELECT DISTINCT m.user_id, dr.d_date FROM messages m, date_range dr) p
  LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT user_id, m_date,
              SUM(m_time <= '16:00') AS before16,
              SUM(m_time > '16:00') AS after16 
         FROM messages
        GROUP BY user_id, m_date
        ORDER BY user_id, m_date ASC) m
    ON p.user_id = m.user_id AND p.d_date = m.m_date;`

Comment: I did, and it has been running for 20 minutes now. I think I know what the problem is. The date_range table holds many duplicate dates (up to 2000 per date). I need to take the dates fro date_range DISTINCT or create an empty date_range table. I oversimplified the situatuation in the OP. So I guess the query should be editted like: `...a16 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(m.user_id), DISTINCT(dr.d_date) FROM messages m, date_range dr) p...`, right? In the OP it appears as if date_range._date has unique values, and your query therefore takes 2000x longer because of all duplicate dates, right?

Comment: Please, provide output of: `SELECT count(*), count(distinct user_id) FROM messages`, `SELECT count(*), count(distinct d_date) FROM date_range` AND `EXPLAIN SELECT p.d_date, p.user_id, ...` of your main query. Note, that queries can take a while.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a shot:

```
select u.user_id, u._date,
    sum(_time <= '16:00') as before16,
    sum(_time > '16:00') as after16
from (
    select m.user_id, d._date
    from messages m
        cross join date_range d
    group by m.user_id, d._date
    ) u
    left join messages m on u.user_id=m.user_id
                        and u._date=m._date
group by u.user_id, u._date
```

The inner query is just building a set of all possible/desired user-date pairs.  It would be more efficient to use a users table, but you didn't mention that you had one, so I won't assume.  otherwise, you just need the `left join` to not remove the non-joined records.

**EDIT**
--More detailed explanation: taking the query apart.

Start with the innermost query; the goal is to get a list of all desired dates for every user.  Since there's a table of users and a table of dates it can look like this:

```
select distinct u.user_id, d.d_date
from users u
  cross join date_range d
```

The key here is the `cross join`, taking every row in the `users` table and associating it with every row in the `date_range` table.  The `distinct` keyword is really just a shorthand for a `group by` on all columns, and is here just in case there's duplicated data.

Note that there are several other methods of getting this same result set (like in my original query), but this is probably the simplest from both a logical and computational standpoint.

Really, the only other steps are to add the `left join` (associating all of the rows we got above to all available data, and not removing anything that doesn't have any data) and the `group by` and `select` components which are basically the same as you had before.  So, putting everything together it looks like this:

```
select t.user_id, t.d_date,
  sum(m.m_time <= '16:00') as before16,
  sum(m.m_time > '16:00') as after16
from (
    select distinct u.user_id, d.d_date
    from users u
      cross join date_range d
  ) t
  left join messages m on t.user_id = m.user_id
                      and t.d_date = m.m_date
group by t.user_id, t.d_date
```

Based on some other comments/questions, note the explicit use of prefixes for all uses of all tables and sub-queries (which is pretty straight forward since we're not using any table more than once anymore): `u` for the `users` table, `d` for the `date_range` table, `t` for the sub-query containing the dates to use for each user, and `m` for the `message` table.  This is probably where my first explanation fell a little short, since I used the message table twice, both times with the same prefix.  It works there because of the context of both uses (one was in a sub-query), but it probably isn't the best practice.

Comment: Please see the updated OP. I have a user table and have renamed some of the columns (for instance into m_date and d_date) because I got confused trying to understand your query. Would you please update your query so I may understand?

Answer (score 1):

It is not neat. But if you have a `user` table. Then maybe something like this:

```
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    _date, 
    SUM(_time <= '16:00') AS before16, 
    SUM(_time > '16:00') AS after16 
FROM messages 
GROUP BY user_id, _date
UNION
SELECT
    user_id,
    date_range,
    0 AS before16, 
    0 AS after16 
FROM
    users,
    date_range
ORDER BY user_id, _date ASC
```

Comment: While this query will work (and the OP better have a `user` table), it's not completely optimal (Especially given the behaviour of `UNION`).  I'd much prefer a version with explicit joins, and in a single `SELECT` statement.  And I know how that `ORDER BY` is going to react, but it makes me itchy, seeing it like that.

Comment: I get an error: `#1052 - Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous` I don't know what suer_id is being referred to. Any help?

Comment: It is probably not the best solution. I was just giving the Op another option. It was just what came to me first when I saw the output.

Answer (score 0):

chezy525's solution works great, I ported it to postgresql and removed/renamed some aliases:

```
select users_and_dates.user_id, users_and_dates._date,
    SUM(case when _time <= '16:00' then 1 else 0 end) as before16,
    SUM(case when _time > '16:00' then 1 else 0 end) as after16
from (
    select messages.user_id, date_range._date
    from messages 
        cross join date_range 
    group by messages.user_id, date_range._date
    ) users_and_dates
    left join messages  on users_and_dates.user_id=messages.user_id
                    and users_and_dates._date=messages._date
group by users_and_dates.user_id, users_and_dates._date;
```

and ran on my machine, worked perfectly

Comment: Unfortunately, while this might solve the problems of the 'missing' dates, it won't generate `user`s 'missing' (no messages) for those dates.  You're on the right track, though.

Comment: Thanks for the effort though, it is appreciated.

Comment: Didn't see that requirement then. If none of the solutions work, I'll try to find a complete solution in the morning