# MySQL: Get all values inside a date range (even 0s)

Tags: mysql

I have a query that returns the number of created accounts per day, inside a date range. It looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.id), DATE(a.created_date) AS eventDate FROM accounts a WHERE created_date BETWEEN '2007-1-1' AND '2012-10-10' GROUP BY eventDate
```

It returns something like:

```
   count || eventDate
    1    ||  2011-04-27
    2    ||  2011-04-29
    1    ||  2011-05-05
    4    ||  2011-06-09
    1    ||  2011-08-08
    ...etc
```

I would like, however, to obtain 0 on the dates when no accounts were created, so that the result looks like:

```
    count || eventDate
    1    ||  2011-04-27
    0    ||  2011-04-28
    2    ||  2011-04-29
    0    ||  2011-04-30
    etc.
```

How can I do so with a MySQL query?

Comment: you need to have something that generates complete date and do outer join on that.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034668/missing-days-from-sql-call-where-there-is-no-data/10081549#10081549) will help