# Get return even if value doesnt exist in where clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, where-clause

Using PDO.

```
SELECT *
FROM time 
WHERE 
    UserId = :uid AND 
(
    week = :CurrentWeek || 
    week = :PreviousWeek1 || 
    week = :PreviousWeek2 || 
    week = :PreviousWeek3 || 
    week = :PreviousWeek4 || 
    week = :PreviousWeek5 
    ) 
GROUP BY week
ORDER BY week DESC
```

So, I trying to print out the time for the last five weeks plus the current one in a table like this.

```
                v1      v2      v3      v4      v5      
    Person 1    40      40      40      40      40      
    Person 2    39      40      39      40      40
```

The problem is that if for eg. v3 doesnt exsist, it pushes v4 to v3's place. Im looking for something that tries to gets values for all weeks, and if they doesnt exist, it return default value for that column.

I want to solve this problem in the best way. ( I could ofcourse make an loop for each week and get the values one by one, but it has to be an more efficient way )

Comment: why such an ugly comparison chain when you could have `week IN (:CurrentWeek, :PreviousWeek1, etc...)`?

Comment: It is not the best way, but you can do an outer join to "table" with unions. I had a similar issue a while ago but I didn't need to take care about performance, ...

Comment: Thanks for input both of you. I have no idea why Marc, changed it now. Lesson learned. Hmm, that seem abit overkill. Im going with the loop i mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are willing to [generate fake data in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034668/missing-days-from-sql-call-where-there-is-no-data) (which doesn't happen to be efficient at all) you should get the data from the last five weeks and then process in php the gaps (which should be simple). That will indeed be the "best way".

Comment: So in other words, the best way, without flooding it with unnesassary data, is to make a loop for each week?

Comment: Yes, you will have to loop over the results in php to check for the gaps. Much more efficient that juggling with the records in SQL

Comment: Okey, So be it. Thanks for fast response.