# MySQL - Group By Year using 2 columns & Count

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

**I have a table like this:**

```
ID_____StartDate_____EndDate
----------------------------
1______05/01/2012___02/03/2013
2______06/30/2013___07/12/2013
3______02/17/2010___02/17/2013
4______12/10/2012___11/16/2013
```

I'm trying to get a count of the ID's that were active during each year. If the ID was active for multiple years, it would be counted multiple times. I don't want to "hardcode" years into my query because the data is over many many multiple years. (i.e. can't use `CASE YEAR(StartDate) WHEN x then y` or `IF...`

**Desired Result from the table above:**

```
YEAR_____COUNT
2010_____1
2011_____1
2012_____3
2013_____4
```

**I've tried:**

```
SELECT COUNT(ID)
FROM table
WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(StartDate, '%Y-%m') BETWEEN '2013-01' AND '2013-12'
    OR DATE_FORMAT(EndDate, '%Y-%m') BETWEEN '2013-01' AND '2013-12')
```

of course this only is for the year 2013. I also tried:

```
SELECT YEAR(StartDate) AS 'Start Year', YEAR(EndDate) AS 'End Year', COUNT(id)
FROM table
WHERE StartDate IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY YEAR(StartDate);
```

though this gave me just those that started in a given year.

Comment: You can't just generate data without specifying what data to generate. I've added a long explanation on how to do this in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034668/missing-days-from-sql-call-where-there-is-no-data) that you might find useful

Comment: And what if I then decided just to hardcode the dates in?

Comment: Then you should read the link I pasted :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that there is an auxiliary table that contains consecutive numbers from 1 .. to X (where X must be grather than possible number of years in the table):

```
create table series( x int primary key auto_increment );
insert into series( x )
select null from information_schema.tables;
```

then the query might look like:

```
SELECT years.year, count(*)
FROM (
   SELECT mm.min_year + s.x - 1 as year
   FROM (
      SELECT min( year( start_date )) min_year, 
             max( year( end_date )) max_year
      FROM tab
   ) mm
   JOIN series s
   ON s.x <= mm.max_year - mm.min_year + 1
   GROUP BY  mm.min_year + s.x - 1
) years
JOIN tab
ON years.year between year( tab.start_date )
                  and year( tab.end_date )
GROUP BY years.year
;
```

see a demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f49ab/14

Comment: The query [*could* be a little bit simpler](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f49ab/16) but other than that I entirely agree with the idea of using a numbers table for this kind of problem.