# mysql return null if query is blank or empty

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables:

student_records

------------------------------
|  id | student_name |
|     1       |    chesco    |
|     2       |    lorenz    |
|     3       |    bert      |
|     4       |    julius    |
|     5       |    dom       |
------------------------------

student_attendance

-----------------------------------------------------
|  id | student_date |  time_in  |   time_out        
|     1       | 01-01-2013   |  7:00 am  |   12:00 pm
|     1       | 01-02-2013   |  8:00 am  |   12:00 pm
|     3       | 02-14-2013   |  9:00 am  |   12:00 pm
-----------------------------------------------------

and if i run this query

```
select * from student_attendance 
where id in('4','5') 
and date in ('01-01-2013','01-02-2013')
```

how can i make the time_in and time_out null if no record exists but leaving the id and date the same as what is in the query?

or is my query incorrect?

im stuck at this for 3 days already

any help will be appreciated. thanks

update

i have come up to this

SELECT * FROM (select student_name,
case when sa.time_in is null then '' else sa.time_in END as time_in,
case when sa.time_out is null then '' else sa.time_out END as time_out,
case when sa.student_date is null then '01-01-2013' else sa.student_date END as date
from student_records sr left join student_attendance sa
on sa.id = sr.id) as sub where date = '01-01-2013'

but now it doesnt show data who has record on student_records

Comment: `how can i make the time_in and time_out null if no record exists` => So you are asking how to put `null` in a record that does not exist? You will have to somehow create the missing records and then left join against them. This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034668/how-to-generate-data-in-mysql) might be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by ID and date the same as what is in the query? Do you want all combinations, the first one, something else?

Comment: @MostyMostacho yes actually it is like assume that the time_in and time_out if null if no record exists

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment. You'll have to carefully read the answers to that question. No other way of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

A join **from** `student_records` will return null values if the join criteria is not met:

```
SELECT * FROM student_records SR
LEFT JOIN student_attendance SA ON SA.id = SR.id
where SR.id in('4','5') 
and SA.student_date in ('01-01-2013','01-02-2013')
```

I would suggets you put a primary key on your `student_attendance` table as well, and note that it's likely that `student_records` information will be duplicated when it joins multiple records in `student_attendance`, so be prepared for that.

Updated with a SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6b13d/2

Comment: An `inner join` will NOT `return null values if the join criteria is not met`!

Comment: ...but `LEFT` will :)

Comment: That query will not work as you expect. You have no data to join against. Could provide a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) showing the behaviour you're expecting? As I see it, the OP is expecting to have a `null` value in `time_in` for the missing dates, such as `01-03-2013`.

Comment: thanks for the help, i already tried that, it returns null but when the condition is not met, it returns blank which i wanted to be null for each student.

Comment: You could change your `AND student_date...` to `AND (student_date... OR student_date IS NULL)`

Comment: @scrowler i have come to that also, but the my real problem is when i search for the date that is not in the student attendace which is supposed to return no rows and i will assume that for each student there will be a time_in and time_out that is null

Comment: Try putting your `date in` into your fields: `SELECT student_records.*, IF(student_date IN('01-01-2013', '01-02-2013'), student_date, null) FROM...` etc - this way it will return the date if it exists or null if it doesn't. You can still select the results your first table

Comment: i have come up to this

SELECT * FROM (select student_name,
case when sa.time_in is null then '' else sa.time_in END as time_in,
case when sa.time_out is null then '' else sa.time_out END as time_out,
case when sa.student_date is null then '01-01-2013' else sa.student_date END as date
from student_records sr left join student_attendance sa
on sa.id = sr.id) as sub where date = '01-01-2013'

but it doesnt show bert.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want to return, and I don't really see a situation where this would be useful, but perhaps a union would be helpful:

```
select * from student_attendance 
where id in('4','5') 
and date in ('01-01-2013','01-02-2013')

UNION

select 4, '01-01-2013', NULL, NULL
where not exists (
    select * from student_attendance 
    where id in('4','5') 
    and date in ('01-01-2013','01-02-2013'))
```

Obviously, I repeat this query, and only give you the first combination. (I'm not sure if you want all of them, one of them, etc.). So it's a very bad approach, but hopefully a jumping off point for you.