# mysql How to create aplhabetical sequence numbers A1, A2, A3 etc

Tags: mysql, sequence

I have to create a lot of records in mysql table like this:

A1, A2, A3,....,A24, B1, B2, B3...,B24,...,G1, G2, etc

does anyone know how to do this automatically with a create statement?

I don't want to create them manually one by one.

I am not posting and code that I tried because I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10081549/460557 would help

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use a tool like [mockaroo](https://www.mockaroo.com/)

You can use functions against a field for generation and it supports ruby syntax. So you can do something like this.

`('a'..'z').to_a` or `('0'..'9').to_a` and iterate and append.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example for you. Just put complete range of numbers and alphabets into it and you'll get the sequence.

```
-- create table for Numbers
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_table_1
(`number` INT);
INSERT INTO temp_table_1(`number`) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9);

-- create table for Alphabets
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_table_2
(`alphabet` varchar(1));
INSERT INTO temp_table_2(`alphabet`) VALUES ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D');

-- temp table to insert records "ONLY TO TEST"
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_table_3
(`alphabet` varchar(2));

-- insert into your table
INSERT INTO temp_table_3
SELECT CONCAT(`temp_table_2`.alphabet, `temp_table_1`.number) as `sequence`
FROM `temp_table_1`
CROSS JOIN `temp_table_2`;

-- select inserted data "ONLY TO TEST"
SELECT * from temp_table_3;
```