# MySQL delete rows with subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, delete-row

I want to delete duplicated rows from my link table. This select query here does work:

```
SELECT *
from LINKS t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    from LINKS t2
    where t2.cntid = t1.cntid
        and t2.title= t1.title
        and t2.lnkid > t1.lnkid
);
```

when I change the same query to delete:

```
    DELETE from LINKS t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    from LINKS t2
    where t2.cntid = t1.cntid
        and t2.title= t1.title
        and t2.lnkid > t1.lnkid
);
```

it does not work anymore and states: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax

What is the issue here? Can someone please help to fix the query?

Comment: Because `DELETE` and `SELECT` have different syntax, aren't them?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do that only using `JOIN` without `EXISTS` and inline view as follows:

```
DELETE t1
FROM LINKS t1, LINKS t2
WHERE t2.cntid = t1.cntid
    AND t2.title= t1.title
    AND t2.lnkid > t1.lnkid
```

This is faster than using `EXISTS`. of course, you SELECT can be converted like this.

```
SELECT *
from LINKS t1, LINKS t2
WHERE t2.cntid = t1.cntid
    AND t2.title= t1.title
    AND t2.lnkid > t1.lnkid
```

If you try DELETE, plz `set autocommit = '0'`

Comment: Thank you, the delete query is working now. However, since there are a couple of million duplicated rows, the delete query is running for more than an hour now and no end in sight. Can I speed things up somehow?

Comment: @sub hard to typing. I am using smartphone moreover my english is not good. Can you try my answer on other question? I really want to know this nswer improve you. Plz let me know. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929000/slow-mysql-query-on-update-statement/19929325#19929325

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
DELETE t1 from LINKS t1 
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * from (select * from LINKS) t2 
                   where t2.cntid = t1.cntid 
                   and t2.title= t1.title 
                   and t2.lnkid > t1.lnkid);
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a1f95/1)