# Use Access (SQL) query to group (histogram) data by date with multiple fields

Tags: sql, ms-access, sharepoint, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I'm looking to try and put together a histogram for returns and group it by division, but just for an example, let's say we have drivers that are prone to crashing cars.  I want to know how many times each driver has crashed a car in each quarter so I can see if they're getting better worse at the whole driving thing.

Here's a table of example data:

```
crash_date  driver  car
10/26/2013  Jane    Hundo
11/3/2013   Bob     Hundo
11/6/2013   John    Ferd
11/12/2013  John    Superoo
11/12/2013  Bob     Ferd
1/20/2014   John    Superoo
3/5/2014    John    Superoo
3/17/2014   Bob     Superoo
5/24/2014   Bob     Hundo
```

What I'd like to get is the number of crashes organized by driver and quarter:

```
Quarter Bob     Jane    John
Q4Y13   2       1       2
Q1Y14   1       0       2
Q2Y14   1       0       0
Q3Y14   0       0       0
```

Using the info from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764881/mysql-getting-data-for-histogram-plot) got me this far:

```
SELECT  crash_year as Year, Count(*) as Bob
FROM    (SELECT  year(crash_date) as crash_year
        FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT crash_date, driver
                FROM            crash_table
                WHERE           driver = "Bob") AS subQuery1) AS subQuery2
GROUP   BY crash_year
ORDER   BY crash_year;
```

Which gives me this result:

```
Year    Bob
2013    2
2014    2
```

I haven't had much more luck with my searches up to this point, but I'll keep poking around.

Comment: Have you tried ms-access `pivot`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546305/pivoting-data-in-ms-access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work with a dynamic number of drivers

```
TRANSFORM Nz(Count(D.driver),0) AS CountOfdriver
SELECT "Q" & DatePart("q",[crash_date]) & "Y" & Year([crash_date]) AS Quarter
FROM Table1 D
GROUP BY "Q" & DatePart("q",[crash_date]) & "Y" & Year([crash_date])
PIVOT D.driver;
```

output looks like this

```
Quarter Bob Jane    John
Q1Y2014 1   0       2
Q2Y2014 1   0       0
Q4Y2013 2   1       2
```

Comment: That's just about perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this does what you want:

```
select datepart("yyyy", crash_date) as yr, datepart("q", crash_date),
       sum(iif(driver = 'Bob', 1, 0)) as Bob,
       sum(iif(driver = 'Jane', 1, 0)) as Jane,
       sum(iif(driver = 'John', 1, 0)) as John
from crash_table
group by datepart("yyyy", crash_date) , datepart("q", crash_date)
order by 1, 2;
```

Comment: Is `quarter` a function in access? I get `sub or function not defined`